# Dynamic predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have started using Prolog and I am having this problem with a dynamic predicate - I don't get the right result.

This is my database:

```
:- dynamic mother/2.

mother(X,Y).

grandemother(X,Y) :- 
    mother(X,A),
    mother(A,Y).
```

These are some of the results I get:

```
1 ?- assert(mother(alice,lise)).
true.

2 ?- assert(mother(lise,kate)).
true.

3 ?- grandemother(alice,X). % should only give X = kate.
true ;
X = lise ;
X = kate ;
true ;
X = kate.

4 ?- grandemother(alice,lise). % should only give false.
true ;
true ;
true ;
false.

5 ?- grandemother(X,kate). % should only give X = alice.
true ;
true ;
X = alice ;
X = alice ;
X = lise.
```

I really don't know where the problem is, any ideas?

Comment: What's the purpose of `mother(X, Y).`? That is stating that `X` is the mother of `Y` no matter what `X` and `Y` are since they're variables.

Comment: i know  i can just put them as facts `mother (alice,lise)` ,..etc , but i wanted to do the instantiation using the assert predicate .

Comment: I mean literally `mother(X, Y).`, the line right after your `dynamic/1` call. That's a "fact" that says anyone is the mother of anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lurker said in his comment, the issue is your line `mother(X,Y).`, directly after the dynamic declaration.

To break down exactly what's happening, I'll look at `grandemother(alice,X)` (after your asserts of `mother(alice,lise)` and `mother(lise,kate)`):

```
grandemother(alice,X) :- mother(alice,A),mother(A,X).
mother(alice,A) unifies with mother(X,Y). This leaves A unbound. 
mother(A,X) unifies with mother(X,Y). This leaves both A and X unbound.
```

Therefore, `grandemother(alice,X)` succeeds without having to bind X.

We ask again, and this time:

```
mother(A,X) unifies with mother(alice,lise). (The second mother/2 fact.)
```

`grandemother(alice,X)` succeeds with X bound to lise. Ask again...

```
mother(A,X) unifies with mother(lise,kate).
```

X is kate. Again...

```
mother(A,X) cannot be unified any more. Backtrack further...
mother(alice,A) unifies with mother(alice,lise).
mother(lise,X) unifies with mother(X,Y). X is unbound.
```

X is unbound again, so we just get `true`. Again...

```
mother(lise,X) unifies with mother(lise,kate).
```

X is kate again. Any more?

```
mother(lise,X) cannot be unified any more. Backtrack further...
mother(alice,A) cannot be unified any more. Backtrack further...
No more backtracking to be done, so there are no more results.
```

So we get no more results.

The solution, as @lurker pointed out, is to remove `mother(X,Y).`, so that this unbound behaviour cannot occur.