# Dynamic predicates and case-sensitivity

Tags: prolog

I have written the following code:

```
:-dynamic [subjectHaveDomain/2].
:-dynamic [objectHaveDomain/2].  

element(X,[X|_]).             % Is X part of the list
element(X,[_|R]) :-
    element(X,R).     

subset([],_).                 % Is [X|R] a subset of K
subset([X|R],K) :-
    element(X,K),
    subset(R,K).

subjectHaveDomain(S,[D1|DN]). 
objectHaveDomain(O,[D1|DN]).  % Subject and objects both have domains

canRead(S,O):-                % Subject can read object if the domain of the object is a subset of the domain of the subject.
    subjectHaveDomain(S,L1),
    objectHaveDomain(O,L2),
    subset(L2,L1).
```

I tried to execute this by asserting objects and subjects, to find all the `Subject`s and `Object`s that make `canRead(Subject,Object)` true, but I don't get the expected results.

```
1 ?- assert(subjectHavedomain(a,[s,p])).
true.

2 ?- assert(subjectHavedomain(b,[s,p,ts])).
true.

3 ?- assert(subjectHavedomain(c,[s])).
true.

4 ?- assert(objectHavedomain(o1,[s])).
true.

5 ?- assert(objectHavedomain(o2,[p,ts])).
true.

6 ?- assert(objectHavedomain(o3,[p])).
true.

7 ?- canRead(S,O).
true ;
true ;
true ;...
```

I am expecting:

```
S = a,
O = o1;
S = a,
O = o3;
S = b,
O = o1;
S = b,
O = o2;
S = b,
O = o3;
S = c,
O = o1;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As with 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354324/dynamic-predicate-in-prolog
the issue is 
subjectHaveDomain(S,[D1|DN]).
objectHaveDomain(O,[D1|DN]).
Don't declare dynamic predicates with variables, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic predicate in Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354324/dynamic-predicate-in-prolog)

Comment: Also your element/2 is essentially just http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2 and subset/2 is http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=subset/2, in case you want to use built-in predicates rather than having to create your own

Comment: i removed them ....but i get this   ` canRead(S,O).
false.`

Comment: Your next issue is that you are asserting subjectHavedomain rather than subjectHaveDomain, and objectHavedomain rather than objectHaveDomain - note that you have a lower-case 'd' on domain, and Prolog is case-sensitive

Comment: yes ...didn't notice that .....thank's bro really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for future reference (given that this was solved in the comments but I loathe questions that are resolved with no answers), we have two issues here:

The first is essentially the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354324/dynamic-predicate-in-prolog), with variables being used in a fact causing issues, compounded by variables in lists allowing for indefinite recursion. The fix is to remove:

```
subjectHaveDomain(S,[D1|DN]).
objectHaveDomain(O,[D1|DN]).
```

The second issue is case-sensitivity on your dynamic predicates vs your asserts. The dynamic predicates are `subjectHaveDomain/2` and `objectHaveDomain/2` but you are asserting `subjectHavedomain/2` and `objectHavedomain/2`, which are different facts.

Finally, as a somewhat pedantic note, the `element/2` predicate is a re-implementation of [member/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2) and the `subset/2` predicate is a re-implementation of [subset/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=subset/2), in case you want to use built-ins rather than having to write your own.